# Is MaxMind.GeoIP2.DatabaseReader Thread Safe?

Tags: .net, multithreading, geoip, maxmind

I intend to use MaxMind.GeoIP2 in a high traffic environment, that means a lot of threads will be sharing the MaxMind.GeoIP2.DatabaseReader. The documentation is not clear, and I would like to know if it is thread safe?

This is the documentation I use http://maxmind.github.io/GeoIP2-dotnet/doc/v0.4.0/index.html ( and I believe it's the latest available version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is thread safe. The documentation says that the API fully supports use in multi-threaded applications. You should share the reader object among many threads. Please see the link --
https://github.com/maxmind/MaxMind-DB-Reader-java/blob/master/README.md

[Also, if you check the source code, there is a test for multi-threading.](https://github.com/maxmind/MaxMind-DB-Reader-java/blob/master/src/test/java/com/maxmind/db/MultiThreadedTest.java)

Hope that helps !

Comment: Are you referring to .NET or Java?

Comment: It is similarly documented for the [.NET API](https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-dotnet#multi-threaded-use).

Comment: @MichaelC. the question was about .NET, but I believe it's the same for Java and other APIs?